# Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of an abelian group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $H = \{x \in G: x = y^2$ for some $y\in G\}$;  that is, let $H$ be the set of all the elements of $G$ which have a square root.  Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, where $G$ is an abelian group.

So I'm pretty lost in group theory.  I know that I need to prove that for any element, $a,b \in H$, that $(a^{-1} * b) \in H$, where * is the group operation on $G$.   I know that I also need to use the fact that $G$ is abelian.  So somehow commutativity is involved.  But I admit that I have no idea what I am doing.

I guess my primary question is:  What does $x^{-1}$ look like in $H$?

Since $x$ = $y^2$ then $x^{-1} = (y^2)^{-1}$, which is what?

Comment: Okay, you need to show that $a,b\in H\Rightarrow a^{-1}b\in H$. Well, what does it mean for $a,b\in H$? It means $a=x^2$ and $b=y^2$ for some $x,y\in H$. What does it mean for $a^{-1}b\in H$? It means $a^{-1}b=z^2$ for some $z\in H$. How do we write $a^{-1}b$ as a square of some $z$ if we know $a$ and $b$ are squares of $x$ and $y$ (resp)? Well, $a^{-1}b=(x^2)^{-1}(y^2)=(x^{-1}y)^2$ so $a^{-1}b=z^2$ where $z=x^{-1}y$. The entire proof is unpackaging and repackaging statements into equivalent forms.

Comment: * is not just some operation on $G$, it is the group operation.

Answer (score 1):

No, $H$ is rather the set of the square elements.

Assume that $a,b\in H$, then we have $a=x^2$ and $b=y^2$ for some elements $x,y\in G$. Then $a^{-1}b$ will be the square of which element (using commutativity)?

Comment: Having a square root and being a square are the same thing.

Comment: I agree with Robert.  The statement of the problem comes directly from the book and that's the wording they use.  But it's equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

$H$ is the image of the map $x \mapsto x^2$. Since $G$ is abelian, this map is a homomorphism and so $H$ is a subgroup, being the image of a homomorphism.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have to assume that $G$ is abelian is that for example, if $x^2,y^2 \in H$ then you get that you want to show $x^2y^2 \in H$. So what you want is that $x^2y^2$ is a square, and the natural choice is $(xy)^2 = xyxy$. Commutativity gives you $x^2y^2 =xyxy$. The reason that inverses are in $H$ is that $(y^2)^{-1} = (y^{-1})^2$, you can verify this by multiplying by $y^2 = y*y$. This does not require that $G$ is abelian.