# Subgroup of abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be abelian group and $H=\{ x^{2}/x\in G\}$

- $H$ is it a subgroup of $G$ ?

H is subset of a group G is a subgroup if :

(i)$\quad  e \in H$ (e is The identity element of G)

(ii) if $x, y \in H$, then $x\ast y \in H;$

(iii) if $x \in H$, then $x^{-1} \in H.$

indeed,

For  ii) let $x,y \in H$ then $x \ast y=(xy) \in H$ 
i'm stuck in that level so i can't prove (i) or (ii) true or flase

- If H is subgroup of G can i general that  for  $H^{n}=\{ x^{n}/x\in
     G\}\quad  \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $

Comment: if $x,y \in H$ you can write them $x=x'^2,y=y'^2$ by definition. Then, in abelian group, you have that $(ab)^n=a^n b^n$, thus $xy=x'^2 y'^2 = (x'y')^2 \in H$. For the inverse, in any group you have $(x^k)^{-1}=(x^{-1})^k$ (you can easily check it using definition of "power", which is product iterated $k$ times), so if $x=x'^2 \in H$, then $x^{-1}=(x'^{-1})^2 \in H$

Comment: @Yann Hamdaoui  Thanks what about the (i)

Comment: $e=e^2\in H$, right?

Comment: @drhab so H is subgroup of G

Comment: Yes. If $A$ is an abelian group then you have subgroups $nA:=\{na|a\in A\}$ (additive notation) for nonnegative integers $n$.

Comment: @drhab  Thanks but in our case is (multipulication notation )

Comment: Notation is not of essential importance. It is just a good custom to switch to additive notation if the group is abelian.

Comment: sorry i'm confused between groups (one law ) and ring ( two laws) that's why i said " so we can say for example that $3H=\{ 3x=x+x+x / x\in G\}$ and $H^{3}=\{x^{3}=x\ast x\ast x/x \in G\}$ they are subgroups of G"

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537587/prove-that-h-is-a-subgroup-of-an-abelian-group-g.